# Number of ways to arrange the alphabet, A is not in first position, B is not in second, and so on.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

My first answer was 25! as The first letter has 25 possibilities, second letter 24 possibilities, and so on. However, I realised that it is actually more than that. There is a possibility that the first letter is B, and this means that the second letter also has 25 possibilities making the calculation 25*25*23*22... which is more than 25!.

So I attempted to calculate the number of possibilities by subtracting the number of combinations which has A in the first position, B in the second position, and so on from 26!. But I am having difficulties in doing so. The number if combinations where A is the first letter is 25!. The number of combinations where B is the second letter is also 25! but the combinations with A as the first letter must be excluded. This is the part where I am having trouble with, calculating the possibilities which should be excluded, and it just gets more complicated as more possibilities has to be excluded.

All I know now is that the answer is in between 25! and 26!. What is the simplest method in solving this problem?

Comment: This is called a derangement.  It's hard to solve numerically exactly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: It turns out that for $n\ge 1$ the number of derangements of $n$ things is the integer closest to $\frac{n!}e$, which is $$\left\lfloor\frac{n!}e+\frac12\right\rfloor\;.$$ When $n=26$, this is a very large number, somewhat more than $1.48\times 10^{26}$. The online calculator [here](http://apfloat.appspot.com) says that it’s exactly $$148362637348470135821287825\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is called a derangement. It's hard to solve numerically exactly.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

as n approaches infinity, permutation(n) divided by derangement(n) is 1/e